# Why is Pycharm generating .bak files

Tags: python, pycharm

My Pycharm started to generate .bak files, for example views.py.bak for file views.py
These files are backup files, so I'm guessing that there should be some option to disable/activate bak files. 
Solution?

Comment: Are you sure it's PyCharm generating these files and not some other editor? Did you install any plug-ins for PyCharm?

Answer (score 2):

Third-party modules will create the .bak files. 
Example -  WinMerge : [winmerge documentation](https://manual.winmerge.org/en/Configuration.html)  
 Also, developers used to keep the backup copy naming like this ".bak , .old , .new and so on."  
Wiki link : [Bak File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bak_file)

---

(As per the win Merge Documentation guide below) 
**Backup Files page** 

This page allows you to control how WinMerge creates backup files.

1. Create backup files in
   Specify when WinMerge should create backup files. You can enable or disable each of these options independently:

Folder compare (disabled by default): Backup files are create whenever files are overwritten (copied).

File compare (enabled by default): Backup files are created whenever files are saved.

2. Create backup files into
   Specify where backup files are created. Only one of these options can be enabled:

Original file's folder (enabled by default): Backup files are created in the same folder as the source file. This is usually a good choice. The down side is that cleaning up backup files in big folders can take a lot of work.

Global backup folder (disabled by default): All backup files are created in one global folder. This makes them easy to clean up. But, if there are multiple source files with same file name, then the most recent backup file overwrites the previous one of the same name.

3. Backup filename
   When WinMerge creates a backup file, it appends an extension to the source file name. You can choose either or both of these extension schemes:

Append .bak -extension (enabled by default): For example, the file.txt is backed up to file.txt.bak.

File compare (enabled by default): Timestamps are almost always unique, so this option usually avoids duplicating backup file names when the source files have the same names.

Also, storing a copy of a file each time you save it provides a way to track changes to the file. However, you should consider that this option can create a lot of files.

---